# How can I reduce the length of the line from sides?

Tags: css

I managed to highlight the active menu item with a red colour bottom border. But I would like to cut it short from the sides. This is my existing code.

```
.nav-regular .nav-item.level0:hover > a
 {
 background-color: ;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #f00;
 }
```

[see screenshot](http://monosnap.com/image/Rg1vHmcnjwE2ek3jHXO8dbb6WQkVOg)

Comment: Take a look at `padding` and `margin` css properties

Answer (score 1):

Give Border left and right for this

```
border-left: 1px solid;
```

but border takes space for use it may affects on the spacing  My suggession is to use this for all menu and when active change color of bottom

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to shorten the bottom border length use this:

```
border-bottom-width: given length;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the padding from the  link and instead add the padding in the parent tag.

Before:

```
<ul><li><a href="#" style="padding:0 10px">test</a></li></ul>
```

Change to:

```
<ul><li style="padding:0 10px"><a href="#">test</a></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove padding of a tag and give margin li to space between link**

```
.nav-regular .nav-item li{
         margin: 0 10px;
        }
        .nav-regular .nav-item.level0 > a
         {

        paddin-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
         }
```